# Programmatically specifying pathauto alias

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I am working on a custom module to specify the pathauto alias of a new node, based on taxonomy terms that a user sets when they create the node. For instance, for my `blog post` content type, the alias would be auto-generated as `/blogs/this-is-a-new-blog-post`. However, if the `category` taxonomy is set to be `special-project`, I want to change the alias to be `/special-project/blog/this-is-a-new-blog-post`.

I'm able to load the node using `hook_entity_insert()`. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to set the alias.

I've found examples of how to set the path when creating a new node, but I already have an existing node object in this hook. I've tried debugging the path from the entity using `$entity->toUrl()->getInternalPath()`, but that just gives me the default URL (`/node/123`), not the alias. Trying to debug `$node->path`, I get an enormous `stdClass` object that I can't really suss out. Trying to debug `$node->path->alias` using `drupal_set_message("alias: " . $node->path->alias);`, I get this: `alias:`.

How can I see and alter the path alias on an existing node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Shawn Conn pointed out, there are pathauto hooks that I can use instead. What I wound up using was `hook_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, array &$context)`. The `$context` has the node entity object in `$context['data']['node']`, and `$alias` is the literal alias string. Since it's passed by reference, no need to perform any save function after changing it. Very easy to do what I need to in there.

Answer (score 5):

Pathauto 8.x is already [hooking into](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/pathauto/blob/8.x-1.x/pathauto.module) the `hook_entity_$CRUD_OP()` hooks of D8 to do its work. Thus, trying to do this via a `hook_entity_insert()` means your module hook might fire before/after pathauto has set its alias (depending on module weight).

Instead of doing this, you should use the [API functions](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/pathauto/blob/8.x-1.x/pathauto.api.php) of pathauto to alter its behavior. For example, `hook_pathauto_pattern_alter()` or `hook_pathauto_alias_alter()` will let you alter the pattern/alias prior to generation/saving.

See [`pathauto.api.php`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/pathauto/blob/8.x-1.x/pathauto.api.php) for more info.